# How to get the record that was inserted by sync

Tags: laravel

Is there a way to get the record or records that was inserted by sync method?

Something like:

```
$shop_product = $shop->products()->sync(1);
```

so I want now $shop_product to be instance that contains the records

```
{
shop_id: 1,
product_id: 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sync method updates your products relationship with shop. 
So calling `$shop->products` should return you only products that you synced. 
There is no reason to access pivot table data unless you have some additional data there. If you have then you should define in your model relationship that you want it. Like:

```
return $this->manyToMany(.....)->withPivot(['data_field_name'])
```

If you are working with shop products you probably don't need pivot table. Usually one product can be related to only one shop so relation will be $this->hasMany(Product::class) and your products table will have shop_id